# JPA Specification - Check values in multiple rows

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a one to many relationship in my database, which after joining looks like this:

```
 Person id | Attribute id
--------------------------
     A     |      1
     A     |      2
     A     |      3
```

What I'm trying to do is return a Person if it has a list of Attributes I'm passing as a parameter, using Specification for filtering with JPARepository, but having multiple rows for the same Person is giving me some trouble, I don't know how to do it.

As a sample of some code of the Specification:

```
public static Specification<Person> hasAllAttributes(List<Long> attr) {

    return (root, query, cb) -> {
       Root<Attribute> rootA = query.from(Attribute.class);
        root.alias("p");
        rootA.alias("at");

        Predicate samePerson = cb.equal(root.get(Person_.ID), rootA.get(Attribute_.PERSON));

        Predicate hasAttribute = rootA.get(Attribute_.ID).in(attr);

        return cb.and(samePerson, hasAttribute);
    };
}
```

This makes it work like an or, it returns the Person if it has one of the Attributes, returning it several times if it contains more than one of those in the list. So this is not actually what I'm looking for, I guess it is incomplete, but I have no idea how to add this restriction.

Comment: sharing the code would help to suggest. Something like this: `Person findTopByAttributesIn(List<String> attributes);`, will return one person, if you are interested in just one person matching the attributes.

Comment: You're right, I didn't post any code because it isn't wrong, but rather incomplete, I think. But it can help to guide and clarify the point I'm in right now. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: Maybe there's a simpler way, but I usually do that by returning all persons for which the number of attributes in the provided list is equal to the size of the provided list. This needs a correlated count subquery.

Comment: Could you post some illustrating code on how to form that subquery? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I just had to understand subqueries, then use one to match attributes with the list and count the matches to check that all the ones on the list are returned:

```
public static Specification<Person> hasAllAttributes(List<Long> attr) {

    return (root, query, cb) -> {

        Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<Attribute> subRoot = subquery.from(Attribute.class);
        subquery.select(cb.count(subRoot));

        Predicate samePerson = cb.equal(root.get(Person_.ID), subRoot.get(Attribute_.PERSON));
        Predicate attributeInList = subRoot.get(Attribute_.ID).in(attr);

        subquery.where(cb.and(samePerson, attributeInList));

        return cb.equal(subquery, attr.size());
    };
}
```